# "the package libcheese7:i386 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy2 can't be configured since the version of libcheese7:amd64 is different (3.6.2-0ubuntu3)

Tags: dpkg

When i try to install any software i obtain this error:

```
 libcheese7:i386
 libcheese-gtk23:i386
 empathy
 mcp-account-manager-uoa
 account-plugin-aim
 account-plugin-jabber
 account-plugin-salut
 account-plugin-yahoo
 gnome-contacts
 gnome-control-center
 nautilus-sendto-empathy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I use this machine:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy
```

With the version of ubuntu is :

```
Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:25:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

When i make:  `sudo apt-get install -f` i obtain :

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 535 non mis à jour.
11 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
dpkg: erreur de traitement de libcheese7:i386 (--configure) :
 le paquet libcheese7:i386 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy2 ne peut pas être configuré parce que la version de libcheese7:amd64 est différente (3.6.2-0ubuntu3)
dpkg: erreur de traitement de libcheese-gtk23:i386 (--configure) :
 le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy2 ne peut pas être configuré parce que la version de libcheese-gtk23:amd64 est différente (3.6.2-0ubuntu3)
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de empathy :
 empathy dépend de libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de empathy (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » n'a été créé car le message d'erreur indique une erreur consécutive à un échec précédent.
                                  dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de mcp-account-manager-uoa :
 mcp-account-manager-uoa dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 mcp-account-manager-uoa dépend de libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.0.1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de mcp-account-manager-uoa (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de account-plugin-aim :
 account-plugin-aim dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 account-plugin-aim dépend de mcp-account-manager-uoa ; cependant :
 Le paquet mcp-account-manager-uoa n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de account-plugin-aim (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances eAucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                    Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
    mpêchent la configuration de account-plugin-jabber :
 account-plugin-jabber dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 account-plugin-jabber dépend de mcp-account-manager-uoa ; cependant :
 Le paquet mcp-account-manager-uoa n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de account-plugin-jabber (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de account-plugin-salut :
 account-plugin-salut dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 account-plugin-salut dépend de mcp-account-manager-uoa ; cependant :Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint

 Le paquet mcp-account-manager-uoa n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de account-plugin-salut (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de account-plugin-yahoo :
 account-plugin-yahoo dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 account-plugin-yahoo dépend de mcp-account-manager-uoa ; cependant :
 Le paquet mcp-account-manager-uoa n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de account-plugin-yahoo (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de gnome-contacts :
 gnome-contacts dépend de libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.
 gnome-contacts dépend de libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese7:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de gnome-contacts (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de gnome-control-center :
 gnome-control-center dépend de libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.
 gnome-control-center dépend de libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese7:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de gnome-control-center (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                dpkg: des problèmes de dépendances empêchent la configuration de nautilus-sendto-empathy :
 nautilus-sendto-empathy dépend de empathy (= 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy3) ; cependant :
 Le paquet empathy n'est pas encore configuré.
 nautilus-sendto-empathy dépend de libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.0.1) ; cependant :
 Le paquet libcheese-gtk23:i386 n'est pas encore configuré.

dpkg: erreur de traitement de nautilus-sendto-empathy (--configure) :
 problèmes de dépendances - laissé non configuré
Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
                                                                Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 libcheese7:i386
 libcheese-gtk23:i386
 empathy
 mcp-account-manager-uoa
 account-plugin-aim
 account-plugin-jabber
 account-plugin-salut
 account-plugin-yahoo
 gnome-contacts
 gnome-control-center
 nautilus-sendto-empathy
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why this error and how can i correct it please ?

Comment: post the whole output of `sudo apt-get install -f` command

Comment: I obtain the same error when i make sudo apt-get install -f

Comment: posted details is not enough so i ask you to post the full output.

Comment: I posted the details

Answer (score 1):

There is a conflict between 32-bit and 64-bit packages:

```
dpkg: error processing libcheese7 : i386 (- configure) :
 libcheese7 the package: i386 3.10.2 -0ubuntu1 ~ saucy2 can not be configured
 because the version of libcheese7 : amd64 is different ( 3.6.2 - 0ubuntu3 )
```

How did you get into this situation? Why do you have a 32-bit i686 kernel and 64-bit packages? If you have a 64-bit system, then you should be running an amd64 kernel. You can install the amd64 kernel and remove the  libcheese7:i386 and libcheese-gtk23:i386 packages but it is possible that your system will still be broken:

```
apt-get remove libcheese7:i386
apt-get install linux-image-generic
```

If you have somehow ended up with a odd 32-bit kernel and mixed i386/amd64 system, it might be easiest to install from scratch a new amd64 system.